# Openshift doesent allow mlab ports?

Tags: python, mongodb, openshift, pymongo, mlab

I just created an application in OpenShift, in the past, that was working, but now it says:

`.../site-packages/pymongo/uri_parser.py", line 145, in parse_host % (port,)) ValueError: Port must be an integer between 0 and 65535:`

The problem is that the port doesent belong to OpenShift, but to ***Mlab*** :

```
dbuser=os.environ["USR"]
dbpassword=os.environ["PWD"]

uri = "mongodb://{}:{}@appid.mlab.com:33338/appName".format(dbuser, dbpassword)
```

The port is **33338** but this one doesent belong to Openshift ?!

NB: it seems OpenShift thinks that **dbpassword** is the port number ?

Comment: Are there any special characters in your password that might be messing with the uri parser?

Comment: @pneumee no , only letters+numbers